# WIFI disconnected immediately after Windows built-in PPTP vpn is connected

Tags: windows-10, vpn

WIFI is always disconnected immediately after Windows built-in PPTP vpn is connected. Why the vpn is disconnected, the wifi is connected again.

1. I am 100% sure it is the problem of Windows, not the problem of vpn server or the router or firewall or any other settings. This is replicable on many windows computers.
2. I've tried all methods found online. Including flushing DNS, changing MTU, restore settings, unclick default gateway, disable firewall, etc. None of them work.

It is replicable on both win 10 and win 11. Similar problem occur when using Cisco vpn. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

> WIFI is always disconnected immediately after Windows built-in PPTP
> vpn is connected.

Microsoft PPTP defaults to no split tunnel (and the Cisco App you are using may do the same thing).

Because of this, they limit TCP/IP connections to run through the tunnel. That is why you see what you are experiencing.

It may be possible to enable split tunneling.  Make sure the company is aware.

Comment: https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000997 If your split tunneling means unclick the "default gateway", then it does not work T.T